# my windows 7 'search program and files ' not functioning

Tags: windows-7, desktop-search

For last few weeks the search bar at the very bottom of windows main navigation is not working. Can anybody give the possible ways to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try rebuilding your search index.  Open the *Control Panel*, select *Indexing Options*, choose *Advanced*, and click the *Rebuild* button:

[image: Control Panel - Indexing Options - Advanced - Rebuild]

Answer (score 4):

I did an awfully simple thing - In Taskbar and Start Menu properties, under Start Menu customize, I ticked the box Search with Public Folders. I remembered I unticked that box earlier on. Now I do get search results.

Comment: I had performed the rebuild previously and the search results were the same. This meant the index was not corrupted. Your Start Menu customization to also search Public Folders was really the answer in my situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the Windows logo key + R on your keyboard.
2. In the **Run** box, type **regedit** and then press **ENTER**.
   If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Locate the following registry subkey: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}
4. Right-click this subkey, and then select **Delete**.
   Restart the computer.

**Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977380#top**

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled God Mode(s) on your machine before this happened then you put it in a folder you shouldn't have. Move your God Mode to your desktop and see if your search starts working again.